# jQuery - CSS - Rotate Div by drag mouse event

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, rotation

I'm searching since a few day without real result, maybe someone can help me here.

I've a div on my page (can containt an image, a text area, other), it's draggable and resizable (thanks to jQuery UI), and i want to make it "rotatable", with a handle in a corner to drag and rotate it using css transform (-wekbit-transform, moz-transform)

Is it possible ? with jQuery or other Javascript ?

Actually i don't care of compatibility with IE.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Actually, you can do anything if you don't care about compatibility with IE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using jQuery UI's original drag events:

```
$('selector').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui){
    var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

    $(this).css({
      '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
      '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is that your question is slightly unclear about how the conflict about the two behaviors (when you drag the object both rotates *and* moves around) that arise from this is handled. This one just let the left-right movement of the mouse determine how much to rotate, while the default drag behavior (movement) still exists.

### Edit:

I suppose this is a little hackish but it will work:

```
// Your original element
var ele = $('#selector');

// Create handle dynamically
$('<div></div>').appendTo(ele).attr('id','handle').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'bottom': 5,
    'right': 5,
    'height': 10,
    'width': 10,
    'background-color': 'orange'
});

ele.css('position', 'relative');

$('#handle').draggable({
    handle: '#handle',
    opacity: 0.01, 
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function(event, ui){
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

        $(this).parent().css({
            '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
            '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, starting from your example, i'm on the new to make what i need :)