# jquery rotation plugin - that works like jquery ui resize

Tags: jquery, rotation

I've just noticed that something terrible is missing in jquery-ui. A way to rotate elements, not just drag \ drop \ resize them.

I am aware of a couple of plugins out there to give the ability of rotating images. Though if you notice, all these plugins are **not** supposed to give the end user the ability to rotate  images, but the web master. I am looking for something that comes with a handle (similar to the jquery-ui handle)

Is there any way to incorporate this functionality into my web project? Are there any good plugins out there you know of?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't care about IE7-8 you can use fabric.js https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OMG, it's past a full year.
Anyway...

I think the author of question was looking for something like this
http://vremenno.net/js/jquery-ui-rotation-using-css-transform/

URL to script: http://vremenno.net/examples/jquery-ui-rotation/jquery.ui.rotation.zip

If you need, I can help you with translation of the article.

Comment: Google Translate f or the win!

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility (and shameless plug - I too was missing this plugin and so wrote one) is [jquery-ui-rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable). You can use it something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#target').rotatable();
    });
</script>

<div id="target">Rotate me!</div>
```

It can also be chained with other jQuery UI plugins. For instance:

```
$('#target').rotatable().draggable().resizable();
```

Comment: +1 cool plugin, but you may want to add the relevant code to the answer body, link only answers tend to get deleted

Comment: Good idea! Done so now.

Comment: Nice wowrk, only problem i have when rotating, i can not rotate from center of the element, please take a look http://www.zalepime.com/zalepime_zid.html

Comment: @Gorostas - it looks OK to me. Not sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: godswearhats, You had a lot of bugs there, if I rotate the element and then try to resize or drag its not working correctly because the object is jumping a little. If you like to make a really good Rotatable plugin you need to change the top and left CSS properties of the rotated object according to the degree and then the Draggable and Resizable will work perfectly.

Comment: @RoyShoa Not sure exactly what you mean. Feel free to file a bug against the project on GitHub and I'll take a look :-)

Answer (score 4):

After 5 seconds of googling I found these plugins:

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/
- http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

You might also be interested in http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/ - It adds a lot of functionality to CSS via JavaScript.

Rotating was never part of CSS2, so all cross-browser solutions are mostly workarounds. Be careful while using it!

Comment: thank you, I am aware of these. Though if you notice all these are suppose to give the user the ability to rotate the images, but the web master3. I am looking for something that comes with a handle (similar to the jquery-ui handle). Can't find anything like that

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe you could add this info to your question :-)

Comment: Maybe this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438568/jquery-css-rotate-div-by-drag-mouse-event/3438798#3438798

Comment: right on the spot. Going to check out what's going on there. Thank you