# jquery div rotation with handle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to rotate the div, but with a `handle ( button on its top-right corner )`, i tried but i did`nt get success, so if there is any plugin which do this job for me then please let me know? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probabely find a solution here:
[jQuery - CSS - Rotate Div by drag mouse event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438568/982112)
It's kind of a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) in particular the [Intermediate Demos (Part 2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) using the next button from the next / prev demo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divWrapper">
    <a href="#" id="handle">Rotate</a>

    <div id="divRotate">
        <div>This is content One...</div>
        <div>This is content Two...</div>
        <div>This is content Three...</div>
        <div>This is content Four...</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$('#divRotate').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#handle'
});​
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Scj/)**

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be jquery you can use CSS3.

I made a small sample script with CSS3 rotate.

```
<style>
.divClass:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.divClass {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:orange;
}

</style>

<div class="divClass">
    <button style="float: right">42</button>
</div>
```

You can put it in a html file and look if it is what you want.

I actually don't know if its supported by all the major browsers, I just tested it in Chrome.

Comment: this code works, but i want to rotate the div on pressing the button and when i leave the button it stops rotating

Comment: Ok. Then I misunderstood you. That you can't do only with CSS3, for a click event you need JavaScript/Jquery.